# Algorand - is approving a logicsig a transaction on the chain?

Tags: algorand

Just wondering what happens when I approve a logicsig. I don't see a transaction on Algorand and curious what is going on there.

It gives me a `TEAL Address` but AlgoExplor-ing that address doesn't show anything like an App created on behalf of my acct, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you sign a LogicSig, it produces a delegate signature which can be used as your address as the sender.

Smart signatures don't exist on-chain, but they can be pulled from previous transactions and reused by anyone.